# Can "before & after" rebuilding photos be posted, looking for improvement suggestions?

Tags: discussion

I like to rebuild my engines and cars, sometimes I'm undecided to how to improve "visual" things, like "where should I hold this hose?" or "should I chrome or blacken nuts?" etc. So I would share before and after photos looking for suggestions. Can be done?

Answer (score 5):

This would not be a question which would be suitable for the site, mainly because it is opinion driven. Very few things you could post on in this manner would fall within the realm of how this stack works. I could, however, offer that you join us in the [Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), this community's chat room, where we have much more leeway to discuss such matters.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create your own chat room and use it as a diary for updates, storing random tidbits of information and discussion. There are a couple of active examples:

- My [Lumina Diary](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51715/zaids-lumina-diary)
- Zshoulders' [RX-8 Restoration Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54466/rx-8-restoration-room)

Comment: Cool. I made mine at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55921/skoda-120-restoration-log